# Object of abstract class type "cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2" is not allowed. all the methods are pure virtual

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, opencv3.0

I develop the code in VS2015 + OpenCV3.0 in Windows 7 64bit. This is a demo code that I want have a try. And I have tried many demo but I was coming across the same problem:

> object of abstract class type "cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2" is not allowed. all the methods are pure virtual function.

The demo code is:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main() {
    VideoCapture video("1.avi");
    Mat frame, mask, thresholdImage, output;
    //video>>frame;
    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2;
    pMOG2 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgSubtractor(20, 16, true);
    while (true) {
        video >> frame;
        ++frameNum;
        bgSubtractor(frame, mask, 0.001);
        cout << frameNum << endl;
        //imshow("mask",mask);
        //waitKey(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I include a lot of heaerd files but I still can not use the class `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` and what is worse, the class of `BackgroundSubtractorMOG` is shown undeclared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntax has changed from OpenCV 2.9.X. This will work in OpenCV 3.0.0:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main() {
    VideoCapture video("1.avi");
    Mat frame, mask, thresholdImage, output;
    int frameNum = 0;

    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2 = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(20, 16, true);
    while (true) {
        video >> frame;
        ++frameNum;
        pMOG2->apply(frame, mask, 0.001);

        cout << frameNum << endl;
        imshow("mask",mask);
        waitKey(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well. I saw other people wrote"pMOG2 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();"  the only difference is the key word ‘new’. but the result is different.

Comment: @X.F that is syntax from previous versions. E.g. it works for OpenCV 2.4.9

Comment: Where do you find this change? From the website of Opencv?

Comment: @X.F Yes, in OpenCV documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/master/de/de1/group__video__motion.html#ga2beb2dee7a073809ccec60f145b6b29c&gsc.tab=0

Comment: Where do you find this change? From the website of Opencv? I searched the Opencv website but only find some description not the syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is really helpful

Comment: @X.F have a look at [OpenCV Transition Guide](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: this code could be compiled well, but an exception thrown will be shown while running."Exception thrown at 0x196C6A90 (amdocl.dll)***Access violation reading location 0x9A0BBF14.  If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued." this exception also be thrown when I run a demo code from Opnecv website that the link is http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d9d/segment_objects_8cpp-example.html#a21&gsc.tab=0

Comment: @X.F is not related to the code. It should be about your graphics driver or something.. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/30860785-a3e7-4556-989d-4b46751f5014/windows-8-random-programs-stop-responding?forum=w8itproperf

Comment: I debug this exception with F10 and found this exception is thrown  when it runs to the function "apply()" .the demo code will also thrown the exception at this function of "apply()"

Comment: Probably apply uses opencl, and causes the issue with your graphics driver. Update them and you should be ok.

Comment: the good news is that the error with amdocl.dll does not show again after I update the display driver but the bad news is that there is error of "Exception thrown at 0x00000000" I think I need to restart my computer and try again. Thank very much

Comment: The exception is still there "Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in GMMbackground.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued." It is very weird for it happens when the function run over and step to the next function.

Comment: I find that when I read the video file"XXX.MP4" the cap can not capture a frame for it shows nothing after imshow("mask",mask);. the windows is all grey. Is the VideoCapture can not open a video of MP4 ? Or  the ram is not large enough for this video image?(the video is 1920*1080 the memory in my computer is 16G)

Comment: @X.F check that you're not using release libs in debug, or viceversa. To load a video, you need to link to correct library. Usually for me works adding Vfw32.lib